# AADSTS50059 error in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps

For some time, I get an error when I try to log into my Microsoft account from Visual Studio for my Azure subscription.
My Microsoft account is associated to : Outlook.com (obviously), Office 365, Azure and a Windows Developer.

I ignored this message until now, because I could connect to my database, my websites functioning, etc.
But now I need to publish an application in the Windows Store. When I try to generate my Windows app packages, I found the same error:

[image: Message error]

> We could not refresh the credentials for the account
> AADSTS50059: No tenant-identifying information found in either the request or implied by any provided credentials.
>
> Trace ID: eaf34263-377e-41d3-8f72-177827315914
>
> Correlation ID: 15bbcfe8-8bc9-4a83-aa02-288a54e50dd5
>
> Timestamp: 2016-09-19 11:27:20Z

I have already try to clean up cookies, temporary files, another Windows developer account, ...

---

### UPDATES

I have try to download [Azure AD Application Proxy Connector](https://download.msappproxy.net/subscription/d3c8b69d-6bf7-42be-a529-3fe9c2e70c90/connector/download).
[image: Setup failed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem again on **Visual Studio 2017 (15.1)**.

**Solution found:**

You have to go to `REGEDIT`.

Navigate to "`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\ConnectedUser`"

And empty all the values, except EnableAzureRMIdentity (change to true if isn't) :

[image]

To :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you’re trying to sign in through a Microsoft account and not a domain that is part of the organization ID of the directory you are trying to access.
So please make sure that the admin is part of the same domain name as the tenant domain.

For example, if your Azure AD domain is contoso.com, the admin should be admin@contoso.com.

You could refer to [Troubleshoot Application Proxy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-application-proxy-troubleshoot/).

Moreover, this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132413/aadsts90019-no-tenant-identifying-information-found-in-either-the-request-or-im) might be helpful to you. Please also try the answer provided by Rich.

Comment: I don't have Microsoft AAD Application Proxy Connector and on my azure portal, I can not Enable Application Proxy in Azure AD... (I can only download and install the Microsoft Identity Manager reporting agent on your Identity Manager servers from configuration page)

Answer (score 0):

I followed some of the advice for this error, including modifying my registry key, however the error changed.  And it seems that the @Andrés Talavera is also using a sovereign cloud like I am.

I deleted my Environment Picker JSON file and that is when I got this error when I restart Visual Studio.

After deleting the JSON file, located here:  `%localappdata%\.IdentityService\AadConfigurations\AadProvider.Configuration.json`, I restarted VS17 and I got this error. The JSON file seemed to reappear after the restart.  The next time, after I deleted the Registry Key, and removed the JSON file again, SSO worked great.

**Note**:  *It seems to be associated to the Environment Picker and pointing to the Sovereign cloud AAD.*